# Prestashop specific price not displaying on product page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I updated the specific price for a product correctly in Admin, but when going to the front shop product page, it still shows the original price. When i add product to cart, then it shows the correct specific price. I am using prestashop  1.6.0.14. Is there someone else who has this issue or knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked settings for particular customer groups?

Comment: @Bibisha Jacob, could you provide more detailed information? Show us specific price settings.

Comment: Can you please answer your own question please? With details on what the problem was and how you fixed it?

Comment: check if this solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158790/prestashop-1-6-product-showing-wrong-price-combination-when-using-specific-price

Answer (score 1):

You need a fresh version of the files product.tpl and/or product.js. I just solved this by trial and error :). It wasn't an upgrade, I moved a ps site from one server to another, specific price on product page wasn't displaying (was actually there, but hidden, I saw that by mistake on Edge). So, I replaced those two files and it works. Good luck!