# Prestashop 1.6 Product Showing wrong price combination when using specific price discount

Tags: prestashop-1.6

How to repeat:

1. install prestashop 1.6.1.4
2. create a product JEANS - Wholesale price 53.87, Retail price 74.82 (Allow orders When out of stock, No Tax)
3. add specific price discount of 28% to JEANS
4. add product combinations - in my case I want the client to choose a size and a color: `Size - 29W x 30L, Color - Bleach Fade` and `Size - 29W x 30L, Color - Buff`, both with a `Wholesale price`: 29.9, and `Impact on price` - `Decrease` 33.29

result: 
when I go to product page, if I choose the first combination 
`Size - 29W x 30L, Color - Bleach Fade` I get the price 29.9, which is what I expect.

BUT when I choose the second option 
`Size - 29W x 30L, Color - Buff` I get price $53.87 instead of the 29.9 I expected.

NOTE: when I add the product to the cart then it calculate the correct price (29.9) for both combination - thus this bug is only in the product display

How can I fix this?

I assume this is a bug in the code so any code fix will be welcome.

Background:

I'm upgrading my site from PrestaShop™ 1.4.5.1 to 1.6.1.4, I have a complicated site with a lot of proprietary code, however this scenario is not reproducible in the 1.4.5.1, i.e. repeating the same steps result with a correct price (29.9) in the second product.

Note: this is a minimized version of the bug, in a real product I have more combinations, some with the real '74.82' price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this fix to correct the problem:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/56fe9925c2703ba07d13b6ba56a92494d38ba45e

replace the file in this fix with your prestashop installation

Note: if you are not using the default theme than copy the new tpl to your theme folder.